# Woocommerce hook run after an Order been created through REST API

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, rest-api

I'm building a plugin that needs to update data after order creation! I have succeeded in doing that on the website but not in the **REST API**

What I have done is using `woocommerce_thankyou` that working fine after checkout through the website but not the REST API too!!

**So how to do the same function below after Creating an Order through WooCommerce REST API!!**

```php
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'edit_stock_metadata', 10, 1);
function edit_stock_metadata($order_id)
{

    if (!$order_id)
        return;

    // Getting an instance of the order object
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    
    // iterating through each order items (getting product ID and the product object) 
    // (work for simple and variable products)
    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item) {

        if ($item['variation_id'] > 0) {
            $product_id = $item['variation_id']; // variable product
            $variation = new WC_Product_Variation($product_id);
            $stock_qty = intval($variation->get_meta('_stock_multiplier'));
            $item_quantity  = $item->get_quantity(); // Get the item quantity
            $variation->update_meta_data('_stock_multiplier', ($stock_qty - $item_quantity));
            $variation->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i am also looking for like this.. any progress you made.. Dude